# highlighting each email in input tag

Tags: javascript

So, what I am going to do with the input tag is to insert as many as email address inside it.

```
      <input type="text" name="email-tags"/>
```

To make it more user-friendly, I want to highlight each-email which is typed inside it with blue color, it looks similar like a tag in SO question which also has x button to delete the tag.

Can anybody please help me how to do this with javascript?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Short: no cannot be done in an input. Long: see my post in about a minute of 10.

Comment: how about in one div tag or span, or something? Can you please show me how to do that?

Comment: Here you go, a solution to your problem

Comment: How far did you get before you got stuck? As it stands your question appears to be "write this function for me," or "can you recommend a tool to do this for me?" If you've made an attempt please share that attempt (even if it doesn't work) in your question, and explain where/how it fails.

Comment: @DavidThomas,  Yes, I am actually aware about that. But, I have many freak code for this that doesn't seem to work. I even have download an open source script to achieve this. However the script is too long that is difficult to me to read that. So I open this question hoping that there will an answer with short code that I can easily understand how does it work so that I can modify it as how I expect it next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This block of code actually does what you need. It's pretty advanced. I hope it suits your needs. `document.getElementById("test").value` contains the email addresses in an array in this example.

```js
function setInputEmailToExtendedInput()
{
 var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[data-type='email']");
 Array.prototype.slice.call(inputs).forEach(function(element){
  var node = new emailInput();
  if (element.id)
  {
   node.container.id = element.id;
  }
  if (element.className)
  {
   node.container.className = element.className;
  }   
  element.parentElement.replaceChild(node.container, element);
 });
}

 function emailInput() {
   this.container = document.createElement("div");
   this.container.input = document.createElement("input");
   this.container.input.type = "text";
   this.container.style.overflowY = "auto";
   this.container.input.className = "email_input";
   this.container.appendChild(this.container.input);

   this.container.input.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyUpOnEmailInputDisable(this), false);

   this.evaluateTag = evaluateEmailFunction;
   this.deleteTag = deleteEmailFunction;
   this.container.input.addEventListener("paste", emailEvaluateOnChange(this), false);

   Object.defineProperty(this, "value", {
     value: [],
     enumerable: false
   });

   Object.defineProperty(this, "placeholder", {
     get: function() {
       this.container.input.placeholder;
     },
     set: function(value) {
       this.container.input.placeholder = value;
     },
     enumerable: false
   });

 }

 function emailEvaluateOnChange(obj, e) {
   return function(e) {
     obj.evaluateTag(e.target.value);
   }
 }

 function checkKeyUpOnEmailInputDisable(obj, e) {
   return function(e) {
     if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 32) //either enter or space
     {
       obj.evaluateTag(e.target.value);
       return false;
     } else if (e.keyCode == 8) //backspace
     {
       if (e.target.value.length == 0 && obj.value.length > 0) //length of the input is zero.
       {
         //delete tag.
         obj.deleteTag();
         return true;
       }
     } else if (e.keyCode == 27) //escape
     {
       //hide the input helper and blur the input.
       e.target.blur();
       e.preventDefault();
       return false;
     }
   };
 }

 function deleteEmailFunction(tag) {
   if (!tag) {
     //delete the last tag
     var tag = this.value.length - 1;
   }
   this.container.removeChild(this.container.querySelectorAll(".email_element")[tag]);
   this.value.splice(tag, 1);
   if (this.value.length > 0) {
     var marginNode = parseInt(getComputedStyle(this.container.children[0]).getPropertyValue("margin-right"));
     var width = parseInt(this.container.children[0].offsetLeft) * 2; //default padding
     for (var i = 0; i < this.value.length; ++i) {
       //calculate the width of all tags.
       width += parseInt(this.container.children[i].offsetWidth) + marginNode;
     }
     this.container.input.style.width = (this.container.offsetWidth - width) - 20 + "px";
   } else {
     this.container.input.style.width = "100%";
   }
   this.container.input.focus();
 }

 function createEmail(value) {
   var node = document.createElement("span");
   node.className = "email_element";
   node.innerHTML = value;
   return node;
 }

 function evaluateEmailFunction(tagValue) {

   if (tagValue.match(/[a-z0-9!#$%&\'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&\'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/ig)) {
     //email is valid add
     var node = createEmail(tagValue.trim());
     this.container.insertBefore(node, this.container.input);
     this.value.push(tagValue);
     var marginNode = parseInt(getComputedStyle(node).getPropertyValue("margin-right"));
     var width = parseInt(this.container.children[0].offsetLeft) * 2; //default padding
     for (var i = 0; i < this.value.length; ++i) {
       //calculate the width of all tags.
       width += parseInt(this.container.children[i].offsetWidth) + marginNode;
     }
     //set the width of the tag input accordingly.
     this.container.input.style.width = (this.container.offsetWidth - width) - 20 + "px";
     this.container.input.value = "";
     this.container.input.focus();
   }
 }

 RegExp.escape = function(s) {
   return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
 };


    window.addEventListener("load", function(){setInputEmailToExtendedInput()}, false);
```

```css
  div.email_builder {
    width: 500px;
    height: 36px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #777777;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  input.email_input {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    border: 0px solid transparent;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 11pt;
  }
  span.email_element {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 2px 6px 2px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    color: #0059B3;
    font-size: 10pt;
    white-space: nowrap;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  span.email_element > span.email_remove_button {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 10pt;
    white-space: nowrap;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-left: 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  span.email_element > span.email_remove_button:hover {
    color: #660000;
    font-size: 10pt;
    white-space: nowrap;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-left: 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" class="email_builder" id="test" data-type="email" />
```

Comment: thank you very much for the code. I really appreciate it as what is next  I need from this is to post the document.getElementById("test").value with ajax to php. However, I do really want you to give me more from here. Can you please tell me how to add the `X` button in each email address so that the address can be removed when the `x` button is clicked. Once again, thank you so much.

Comment: @Alisa this is just the demo version. For the full version please pay me €200,--. Kidding of course.This comes from my personal library. It's a good start. To allow multiple email addresses you need to capture the matches in `evaluateEmailFunction` and loop over the matches. Shouldn't be too hard to implement. The x-button can be inserted into the template in `createEmail`. To conclude I provided you with a head start, you need to take it on from here. I'm not a coder on your payroll.

Answer (score 1):

how about this:

```
    <from id="form" action="">
<span id="emailInput">
    <input type="text" name="email-tags"/>
</span>
    <span id="test"></span>
</form>

function isValidEmail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
} 
$(function(){
    $('input').keydown(function(event){
        $input = $(this);
        $emailInput = $("#emailInput");
        $("#test").html(event.which);
        switch(event.which){
            //stop for "," ";" and " "
            case 188:
            case 186:
            case 32:
               currentEmail = $.trim($input.val());
               if(isValidEmail(currentEmail)){    
                   $address = $("<span>");
                   $address.addClass("emailAddress");
                   $address.text(currentEmail);
                   $close=$('<span>');
                   $close.addClass("close").text("x");
                   $address.append($close);
                   $input.val("");
                   $input.before($address); 
               }
        }
    });

    $("#emailInput").on("click",".close",function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
```

see here:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/wryjde3z/

Comment: When I tried to copy paste multiple email address inside the input tag, it doesn't highlight each email address. It only highlight the email address when I type it one by one. I need this because the email address which will be inserted into the input tag will be imported such as  from google and yahoo contacts. Can you please help me how to achieve this?

Comment: try this:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/wryjde3z/1/
also added backspace functionallity, if you need more complex behaviour I guess you can take it from here...

Comment: @tripleb, the backspace functionality is very rudimentary. If you hit backspace somewhere in the input it will delete the tag.

Comment: true i really just added that more as a show of concept not as realy functionality, that is what I meant with my comment